# How do I protect my private keys when using github, heroku, and developing locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, heroku

Currently, I put the keys I use to access other API's and the like in the environment.rb file.  That way it is available both when I run locally, and also on heroku.

However, I'd like to start to make my code available publicly via github so i can get some help.

What are the steps I need to do to make this happen, particularly so that I can test locally and test on heroku.

It seems like there's a way on heroku to add the keys from a command line, so they don't need to reside in the ruby-on-rails app.  But what about for local development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move them to an initializer and add the file to .gitignore

EDIT:

There is a directory in config called initializers. This is where you place code that is supposed to run once when your application starts. In the past, environment.rb was used for these settings, but initializers keep things better organized. I would create a file in the initializers directory called "load_keys.rb" or something like that. In this file, you would put the exact code that was in your environment.rb file that you don't want in github.

Comment: hi, sorry, what do you mean by move to an initiailizer?

Comment: No prob, I updated my original post with more info about initializers. I'm assuming you know what .gitignore is since you didn't ask.

Comment: yes, thanks, I'm familiar with .gitignore :) I am familiar with the directory but wasn't sure what to do with it....

Comment: okay I think I get it...so the sequence would probably be: 1) change all the keys (these have been added to the git repository history so if I put it into github all that history would be there as well, no?; 2) move the key assignments to this separate file load_keys.rb, 3) add it to the .gitignore file?

Comment: That sounds about right. Here's some more info if you want to remove the keys from your repo's history http://help.github.com/removing-sensitive-data/

Answer (score 16):

You can use environment variables ([config vars](http://docs.heroku.com/config-vars) on heroku) to store your API keys and not check them into source.

For a [project](http://github.com/dpmcnevin/redactify) that I am working on, I use a fork of [twitter-auth](http://github.com/mbleigh/twitter-auth), and changed it to read the client secret and key from env variables:

http://github.com/dpmcnevin/twitter-auth/blob/ace5d60a8ed8121cca4c97ef30a0cd025b99bfe1/lib/twitter_auth.rb#L68

```
OAuth::Consumer.new(
  ENV['oauth_consumer_key'] || config['oauth_consumer_key'],          
  ENV['oauth_consumer_secret'] || config['oauth_consumer_secret'],
  options 
)
```

I then set up the keys in my `.rvmrc` in the project directory for local use:

```
export oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxxxxxxx
export oauth_consumer_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
rvm ree@redactify
```

And finally set up the environment variables on heroku:

```
$ heroku config:add oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
$ heroku config:add oauth_consumer_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
$ heroku config
DATABASE_URL          => postgres://.....
RACK_ENV              => production
oauth_consumer_key    => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
oauth_consumer_secret => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Then just make sure that your `.rvmrc` is in the `.gitignore` and then you can push to github without exposing any API keys.

Comment: Can't anyone with access to push to your heroku just read the keys with heroku config?

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your private keys in ~/.ssh as usual.
2. Encrypt your private keys with a passphrase.
3. Install [keychain](http://www.funtoo.org/en/security/keychain/intro/).
4. Add `eval $(keychain private-key-file1 private-key-file2 private-key-file3; source ~/.keychain/${HOSTNAME}-sh)` to your ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile or what have you. (See the keychain man page for csh, tcsh, zsh, or whatever)